# How to remove/add active class to a element in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Can somebody help me, I am havig trouble figuring out how to remove/add active class for vertical menu?

HTML

```
<ul class="vertical__menu">
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item--active" href="#">Truck Route</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Location Map</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Major Retailers Map</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.vertical__menu-item {
  color: blue
}
.vertical__menu-item--active {
  color: red    
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul.vertical__menu li a').click(function () {
    $('vertical__menu-item').removeClass("--active");
    $(this).addClass("--active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add/remove the class `.vertical__menu-item--active`, in your code currently you are removing the class `--active` which doesn't exist in your css. You're also not selecting items currently in your jquery and you're missing `.vertical__menu-item` on the first list item in your mark up so it will not be selected when you're trying to remove the  `.vertical__menu-item--active` class, check the working demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.vertical__menu-item').click(function () {
    $('.vertical__menu-item').removeClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
    $(this).addClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
  });
});
```

```css
.vertical__menu-item {
  color: blue
}
.vertical__menu-item--active {
  color: red    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="vertical__menu">
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item vertical__menu-item--active" href="#">Truck Route</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Location Map</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Major Retailers Map</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('vertical__menu-item').removeClass` miss a dot since it's a class selector.

Comment: Daniel, your code adds the active class to clicked link but doesn't remove it from first one.

Comment: @MilosVujinic fixed it.

Comment: @MilosVujinic Glad I could help! Would be great if you would select my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the class from the previous active element then add it to the new one considering the **full class name** and not only its suffix `--active`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.vertical__menu li a').click(function() {
    /*Select only the active element without forgeting the '.' */
    $('.vertical__menu-item--active').removeClass("vertical__menu-item--active");
    /*Adding the class to the current one*/
    $(this).addClass("vertical__menu-item--active");
  });
});
```

```css
.vertical__menu-item {
  color: blue
}

.vertical__menu-item--active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="vertical__menu">
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item--active" href="#">Truck Route</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Location Map</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Major Retailers Map</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just seperate the `vertical__menu-item` to `active`

**html**

```
<ul class="vertical__menu">
    <li><a class="vertical__menu-item active" href="#">Truck Route</a></li>
    <li><a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Location Map</a></li>
    <li><a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#">Major Retailers Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

**style.css**

```
.vertical__menu-item {
    color: blue
}
.vertical__menu-item.active {
    color: red    
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.vertical__menu li a').click(function () {
        $('.vertical__menu-item').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe because he's using BEM